# Slow operations in parallel

Tags: java

I need help with running parallel operations. The goal of the code is to extract a large amount of small files from the same tar in different folders in a very short time
This is the code:

```
public void decompress(File archive, File destination) throws RuntimeException {
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(archive);
         BufferedInputStream buff = new BufferedInputStream(in);
         TarArchiveInputStream is = (TarArchiveInputStream) new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("tar", buff)
    ) {
        TarArchiveEntry entry;
        while ((entry = is.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
            File file = new File(destination, entry.getName());
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            Files.write(file.toPath(), is.readAllBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException | ArchiveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I execute one time this operation, it takes ~900ms
But when I do something like this to execute the same operation, multiple times in parallel it takes 20000ms:

```
ExecutorService EXECUTOR_SERVICE = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
File archive = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    File directory = new File("Dir_" + i);
    EXECUTOR_SERVICE.submit(() -> decompress(archive, directory));
}
```

or

```
File archive = ...;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    File directory = new File("Dir_" + i);
    new Thread(() -> decompress(archive, directory)).start();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Parallel doesn't always speed things up, and (as you're finding out) can slow things down. It's great for in-memory linear operations but doesn't help much when the bottleneck is reading from a disk.

Comment: This doesn't look, at a glance, like a very parallelizable operation.

Comment: Make your code more observable so that you can tell where time is being spent as you increase or decrease the degree of parallelism. Then it doesn't matter who's doing the guessing because there won't be a need for guesswork.

Comment: I've edited something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- One suspicion is that the directories contain many files, hence `File.mkdirs` does needlessly much checks.
- The constructor of `BufferedInputStream` may have a custom buffer size. Never helped much, but it might be with your disk. Also with parallelism it could help to prevent much "disk head movements."
- You probably already tried `Files.copy` but still, it might have a better memory behavior that `readAllBytes`.

So the version becomes (eschewing `File` in favor of `Path`):

```
public void decompress(File archive, File destination) throws RuntimeException {
    final int bufferSize = 1024 * 128;
    Path archivePath = archive.toPath();
    Path destinationPath = destination.toPath();
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(archive);
         BufferedInputStream buff = new BufferedInputStream(in, bufferSize);
         TarArchiveInputStream is = (TarArchiveInputStream)
             new ArchiveStreamFactory().createArchiveInputStream("tar", buff)
    ) {
        Path oldFileParent = destinationPath;
        oldFileParent.createDirectories();
        TarArchiveEntry entry;
        while ((entry = is.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
            Path file = Paths.get(destinationPath, entry.getName());
            Path fileParent = file.getParent();
            if (!fileParent.equals(oldFileParent)) {
                 oldFileParent = fileParent;
                 oldFileParent.createDirectories();
            }
            Files.copy(is, file);
            //Files.write(file, is.readAllBytes());
        }
    } catch (IOException | ArchiveException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Throwing a RuntimeException and capturing the IOException/ArchiveException without throwing it back (as `new IllegalStateException(e)`) is a matter of taste.

Now to adding parallelism: disk output is probably the bottleneck. Writing two files to the same disk in parallel means skipping back and forth on the disk. Small files might just do.

Better seems to parallelize reading a next file and then in another thread write it.
Two threads might theoretically perform better than many threads with enhightened disk traffic. `readAllBytes` might then be appropriate, to let the writing thread not use `is`.

As in the tar entry maybe the file size is kept too, that would allow to check whether `readAllBytes` is efficient enough - for large files.

Logging was mentioned in this question. It is known, that that can consume much time, and with parallelism becomes even more critical. But you seem to be aware of it. You wrote having written your own logger. For a library `System.Logger` is actually best. It is a façade that uses any logger the application provides. This would have prevented the logger vulnaribility hidden in library dependencies of the past year.

Comment: I don't understand how to parallelize the reading and writing of files, if I try to do it I get an IOException (Truncated TAR archive). As for the throwing of RuntimeException it is my mistake, before the code was different and the exception was thrown

Comment: For parallel read & write, the writing thread should not use the reading `is`, that is `Files.copy` , but the bytes read by `readAllBytes`.

Comment: Ok now I understand. What's the fastest method to write a byte array to a file?

Comment: I never saw a sufficient difference, but a MappedByteBuffer on a FileChannel should be fastest. Measure it though.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you are not decompressing the file in parallel here (you are running multiple threads decompressing the same file concurrently, essentially overwriting the result), there may be several reasons for this performance hit. I/O is one, so it depends on the underlying implementation. Also, what is the `Logger` you are using there? While other parts of your code doesn't seem to be shared among multiple threads, the static call to `Logger` is something that is shared.
Also note: java.nio  uses FileChannels which provide synchronous I/O, so depending on how you create the channels, you may get into similar situations (though I don't believe this applies here).

Comment: The logger I am using is a simple class that I wrote
I'm not overwriting the files, what I wrote above is just a sample code, the archive is the same for the various operations but the destination folders are changing

Comment: Yes, I assumed it was a sample code. Can you share the code of the logger itself as well?

Comment: It's slow even without those lines. Here is the code
Logger: https://pastebin.com/JDQ0fQrR
LogLevel: https://pastebin.com/X9vpZ0AH